# CentOS7 の Firefox で HTTP/1.1 の connection close を送信する方法

Tags: centos, firefox, curl

HTTP RequestでConnection Closeを送信する方法を教えてください。
（CentOS7を使用）

例えば、Firefox68.10.0 ESR (64ビット）で、サーバ側に対してHTTP/1.1でアクセスし、Connection Closeを送信したいのですが、どこの設定をすれば良いでしょうか？
Firefoxのブラウザを閉じればconnection closeが走るのかと思ったのですが、そうでもなく具体的なやり方が分かりません。

また、Curlも試しましたが、CurlでもHTTP1.1のconnection closeを出すオプションが見つけられません。
それ以外の方法でも良いのですが何かやり方はありますでしょうか？

Comment: [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) に陥っていませんか？ / 実際には (何らかの理由で) "HTTP 1.1 での Connection Close の送信" が主な課題であり、たまたま思いついた方法が Firefox や curl を使う…ではないですか？

Comment: おっしゃる通り、まさにXY問題に陥っていましたので、質問を修正致しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl コマンドの場合、request header に `Connection: close` を付加します(`-H` オプション)。

```sh
$ curl -vsL -H 'Connection: close' http://example.com/
         :

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection: close
         :

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
         :
< Connection: close
         :

* Closing connection 0
```